# Starcraft 2 Editor: I want to make two players share their income

Tags: map-editor, starcraft-2

I have a scenario where there are 4 teams vs. a raging Zerg horde constantly attacking them. The idea was allow that player 1 & player 2 in the same team share their income, so that one player could focus on getting the income (SCV income as they deliver the goods) and the other defending.

I haven't gotten the trigger right yet. Anyone have some tips for me?

Comment: I don't know a great deal about the starcraft environment / api but presumably you have access to both players balance ... can you not wire them together in such a way that if 1 changes it updates the other? saving you trying to get the engine to share 1 balance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look in triggers for an action called, "Set Alliance Aspect". Then look to have them share "Resource Spending". You might have to run it twice so it works in both directions, I'm not sure. I haven't gotten a chance to play around with this feature, I only recently discovered it myself.

Anyway, good luck. Hope this helps.